# Mesh current method question here?Is this correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis

We have the circuit in the figure.I have to find Vo in terms of Vi.
[image]

So I have the system of equations 
{-Vi+ (1k+1k)*I1- 1k*I2-5=0

5+1k*I2+I2*1k-I1*1k=0

and Vo=1k*I2

We have 5-Vi=2k*I1-I2 and 5=I1-2k*I2 and Vo =1k*I2.I know that I should find I2 in terms of Vi from the first and second equation and then replace it at Vo ok?
So I do that,and I have

I2=(-5-Vi)/3

Now I have Vo=I2*1k= (-5-Vi)/3 Volt

I think that I have made a mistake and Vo should be equal to Vo=-1k* I2?

Comment: Are we to assume that Vi is an ideal voltage source with zero output impedance and can both sink as well as source current?  This makes a huge difference compared to actually trying this with a bench power supply.

Comment: Why not trying node voltage method? It's a single equation to solve.

Comment: But I have solved it ,I just want to know if Vo=-1k*I2 or Vo=Ik*I2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two equations you wrote are correct. You made mistake while re-arranging them. The equations should be:

$$5 + V_i = 2k\times I_1 - 1k\times I_2\tag1$$
$$5 = 1k\times I_1 - 2k\times I_2 \tag2$$

Solving which you will get the value for \$I_2\$. 
$$I_2 = \frac{-5+V_i}{3k}$$

And then,
$$V_o = I_2 \times 1k = (V_i-5)/3$$

It was more easy if nodal analysis or superposition theorem was used.

Comment: I2=(-15-Vi)/3  so I have Vo=(-15-Vi)/3 .... still negative.I think that Vo is -I2*1k?

Comment: @Notyourthing my mistake. Edited the answer

Comment: So now I have I2=(Vi-5)/3 and Vo= (Vi-5)/3 ?